# RegEx for filename in path without query parameter in XSL / XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt, match

This drives me really nuts... I am not a regex pro... sooo

I tried several regex examples online, but none! is working...

What I want to match against:

```
/path1/path2/filename.zip$parameter1=aaaaa
```

What I want to get is:

```
path1

path2
```

and the filename (Without the query parameter/s or leading slash...) so just `filename.zip`

And yeah, I am stuck with XSLT 1.0 ...

Comment: If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, then your question is not about regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="query">/path1/path2/filename.zip$parameter1=aaaaa</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($query, '$')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'/'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to any XML input, the result will be:

```
path1
path2
filename.zip
```

Comment: Close enough, I can´t work with template that way on the machine (dind´t work) but it pointed me at least in the right direction!